# Getting related user attributes in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm new to Phalcon, just trying to write my first application, and facing an issue that the documentation isn't very clear on, which is in regards to getting related information.

At the moment I have 1 controller, the User controller.

```
<?php

class UserController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function homeAction()
    {

        $users = Users::query()
            ->where('id = :id:')
            ->bind(array('id' => '1'))
            ->execute();

        $user = $users->getFirst();

        $this->view->setVar('user', $users->getFirst());

        $primaryStatus = Status::query()
            ->where('userId = :id:')
            ->bind(array('id' => '1'))
            ->execute();

        $this->view->setVar('primaryStatus', $primaryStatus->getFirst());

        $status = Status::query()
            ->where('userId != :id:')
            ->bind(array('id' => '1'))
            ->execute();

        $this->view->setVar('status', $status);

    }

}
```

And I have some models setup, Users, Attributes and UsersAttributes

and my view setup in volt.

This is my Attributes model

```
<?php

class Attributes extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public $id;

    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {

        $this->hasMany('id', 'UsersAttributes', 'attributesId');

    }

}
```

My Users model

```
<?php

/**
 * Users class
 *
 * Represents Holla users
 *
 */
class Users extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public $id;

    public $name;

    public $username;

    public $password;

    public $email;

    public $active;

    public $createdDate;

    public function getSource()
    {

        return 'users';

    }

    public function initialize()
    {

        $this->hasMany('id', 'UsersAttributes', 'userId');
        $this->hasManyToMany(
            'id',
            'UsersAttributes',
            'userId', 'attributeId',
            'Attributes',
            'id'
        );

    }


}
```

and my UsersAttributes model

```
<?php

/**
 * Users attributes class
 *
 * Represents Holla users attributes
 *
 * @Source('usersAttributes');
 *
 */
class UsersAttributes extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public $id;

    public $userId;

    public $attributeId;

    public $attributeValue;

    public function getSource()
    {

        return 'usersAttributes';

    }

    public function initialize()
    {

        $this->belongsTo('userId', 'Users', 'id');
        $this->belongsTo('attributeId', 'Attributes', 'id');

    }

}
```

I have 3 tables

**users**

- id e.g. 1
- name e.g. andre
- username e.g. andrefigueira

**attributes**

- id e.g. 1
- attributeName e.g. profileImage
- attributeDefaultValue e.g. placeholder.jpg

**usersAttributes**

- id e.g. 1
- userId e.g. 1
- attributeId e.g. 1
- attributeValue e.g. andre.jpg

In my controller I am doing a query and assigning the first result to a view property which is the user property, but I cannot figure out how to access specific user attributes from the get related method implementation.

I'd like to be able to in my volt do something like:

The name of the attributes is defined in the attributes table, then assigned a value and user in the usersAttributes table.

{{ user.userAttributes.profileImage }}

How would I go about accomplishing this? I have searched through a lot of different posts and the documentation with little luck...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised my error, everything was working as it should, Phalcon simply won't map my structure database in this way as I define an attribute name in the attributes table, but the user defined value in the usersAttributes table. Hence no way to map it by the standard way so I had to create a new method and instantiate it elsewhere to pass the parameters to my view.

The code I've used to solve the problem is in the Users model and simply appends the attributes as an object to the user result object.

```
public static function fetchUserAttributes($userId)
{

    $modelsManager = Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getModelsManager();

    $phql = '
    SELECT name, attributeValue
    FROM Attributes
    LEFT JOIN UsersAttributes
    ON UsersAttributes.userId = :userId:
    AND Attributes.id = UsersAttributes.attributeId
    ';

    $rows = $modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array('userId' => $userId));

    $attributesObj = new \stdClass();

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {

        $attributesObj->{$row['name']} = $row['attributeValue'];

    }

    return $attributesObj;

}

public function afterFetch()
{

    //Attach user attributes
    $this->attributes = Users::fetchUserAttributes($this->id);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One to many relation returns the container of zero or more records:

```
{% for r in user.userAttributes %}
    {{ r.profileImage }}
{% endfor %}
```